# New database elements only shown by refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have set up a shoutbox / chat for my homepage, but every time i submit a message, which will be stored in a mysql database, i have to refresh the page to see the submitted message in my div box.

The code for div:

```
<form method="post" action="startseite.php">
<div id="message">
<input type="text" name="spind" value="" size="55" maxlength="90">
<button>Senden</button>
</div></form>
```

My Javascript code for the div-container:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);     
    $("button").click(function(){
        var message = $("input").val();
        var old = $("#content").html();

        $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);

    }); 
});
```

The mysql database Code:

```
<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost", "hallo", "123")
or die("Fehler im System");

mysql_select_db("hallo")
or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank war nicht erfolgreich");


$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$message = $_POST['spind'];

$eintrag = "INSERT INTO chat
(user, message)

VALUES
('$user', '$message')";

mysql_query($eintrag);

mysql_close($verbindung);
?>
```

How can i do this, when i want to display the new message automatically on the div when i submit it?

Comment: How do intend to get the message data sent to the server? XHR? POST? That will determine how you update the div box.

Comment: the data is sent by POST

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all is in one file, here's one way to update the div box after posting message.

startseite.php

```
<?php

$spind = '';

$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost", "hallo", "123")
or die("Fehler im System");

mysql_select_db("hallo")
or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank war nicht erfolgreich");

if ( isset($_POST['spind']) ) {
  $spind = $_POST['spind'];

  $user = $_SESSION['username'];
  $message = $spind;

  $eintrag = "INSERT INTO chat
  (user, message)

  VALUES
  ('$user', '$message')";

  mysql_query($eintrag);

  mysql_close($verbindung);

}

?>

<div id="content">
<?php

$eintrag = "SELECT * FROM chat";
$mysql_content = mysql_query($eintrag);
while($into = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_content)) {
  echo '<p><span style="font-variant:small-caps"><span style="font-size:1.5em"><b><span style="text-transform:capitalize">'.$into['user'].'</span> denkt: </b></span><span style="font-size:1.6em">'.$into['message'].'</span></span></p>';
} 

?>
</div>

<form method="post" action="startseite.php">
<div id="message"><?=$spind?>
<input type="text" name="spind" value="" size="55" maxlength="90">
<button>Senden</button>
</div></form>
```

(Of course a lot still missing here, such as database security, session_start, session check, etc. so for entertainment purposes only, not for public consumption. :) Without knowing other requirements, I think XHR would be a more elegant approach. )

And I don't know why you are attaching an event to the form button and capturing the values of "spind" and "content".

Comment: <div id="content">
<?php
$verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost", "hallo", "123")
or die("Fehler im System");

mysql_select_db("hallo")
or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank war nicht erfolgreich");

$eintrag = "SELECT * FROM chat";

$mysql_content = mysql_query($eintrag);

while($into = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_content)) {
echo '<p><span style="font-variant:small-caps"><span style="font-size:1.5em"><b><span style="text-transform:capitalize">'.$into['user'].'</span> denkt: </b></span><span style="font-size:1.6em">'.$into['message'].'</span></span></p>';
}
?>

Comment: session_start is at the top of startseite.php, so i didnt write it on the code here, just in case that its not necessary for my question

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);     
    $("button").click(function(){
        var message = $("input").val();
        var old = $("#content").html();

        $("#content").append(message);

        $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight);

    }); 
});
```

You can also wrap message within some html code and then try appending it.

Comment: when i use .append the sent message is shown for a second in the div box. same problem, only when i refresh the page, i get it inside the div.

Comment: You haven't shown us the html for message div .. please try to show that we can't guess .. i mentioned in my answer in last line "You can also wrap message within some html code"

Comment: The Code for "content" div:   <div id="content"> <?php $verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost", "hallo", "123") or die("Fehler im System"); mysql_select_db("hallo") or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank war nicht erfolgreich"); $eintrag = "SELECT * FROM chat"; $mysql_content = mysql_query($eintrag); while($into = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_content)) { echo '<p><span style="font-variant:small-caps"><span style="font-size:1.5em"><b><span style="text-transform:capitalize">'.$into['user'].'</span> denkt: </b></span><span style="font-size:1.6em">'.$into['message'].'</span></span></p>'; } ?>

Comment: The Code for "message" div: <form method="post" action="startseite.php">
<div id="message">
<input type="text" name="spind" value="" size="55" maxlength="90">
<button>Senden</button>
</div></form>